# Auth assignment database call yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-rbac

I am using Yii2 and using the `yii\rbac\DbManager` for auth assignment.

I was looking at the logs to see where all the database calls are coming from and this query

```
SELECT `b`.* FROM `auth_assignment` `a`, `auth_item` `b` WHERE 
((`a`.`item_name`=`b`.`name`) AND (`a`.`user_id`='91')) AND (`b`.`type`=1)
```

Keeps running  again and again, sometimes 10/15 times in succession.

I have added

```
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        'cache' => 'cache'
    ],
```

As the docs say that will cache the auth assignments (I am using Memcached). But it doesnt seem to work...

Anyone have any idea? Either how to cache it or why it keeps getting called so many times?

Cheers

Comment: Make sure the application component ID for your cache is correct (double check that you really called it "cache"). Also note that the cache feature for yii\rbac\DbManager has been available since version 2.0.3 so check your Yii2 version.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/3168

Only cache `auth_item`, `auth_rule` and `auth_item_child` data. All these
 data are cached as a single entry in cache. Note that
 `auth_assignment` is too big to be cached (imagine a system with
 millions of users).

Answer (score 0):

Add caching in 
vendor/yiisoft/yii2/rbac/DbManager.php 
(Also in all places you need caching)

this code:

> $all_data = $this->db->cache(function ($db) use ($query) {
>                  return $query->all($db);
>                 },360);

---

```
public function getAssignments($userId)
    {
        if (empty($userId)) {
            return [];
        }

        $query = (new Query)
            ->from($this->assignmentTable)
            ->where(['user_id' => (string) $userId]);


        $all_data = $this->db->cache(function ($db) use ($query) {
                   return $query->all($db);
                  },360);


        $assignments = [];
        foreach ($all_data as $row) {
            $assignments[$row['item_name']] = new Assignment([
                'userId' => $row['user_id'],
                'roleName' => $row['item_name'],
                'createdAt' => $row['created_at'],
            ]);
        }

        return $assignments;
    }
```